# jsonfilter with a special character

Tags: json, openwrt

I want to use jsonfilter to read the required key from my json file.

My json file content is:

```
{
    "rootbin": "/bin"
}
```

I want to read the '**rootbin**' key value, so I used the following jsonfilter command:

```
    cat test.json | jsonfilter -e @.rootbin
/bin
```

But I got an error related to the special characters when changing the key to '**root-bin**' in the json file

```
cat test.json | jsonfilter -e @.root-bin
Syntax error: Invalid escape sequence
In expression @.root-bin
Near here ----------^
```

How to use jsonfilter with special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem. Finally I found out that there is also another syntax: `cat test.json | jsonfilter -e '@["root-bin"]`

It works for me.

The help page of *jsonfilter* also refers to this page as allowed patterns https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/.